# How do I use computed with nested Vuex Object

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have an object in Vuex which has the following functionality:

```
// Define the object in the state
myObj = {};
// Add a key and give it an empty array
state.myObj[someNumericalId] = [];
// Add a value to the array
state.myObj[someNumericalId].push['someData'];
```

How do I get notified of changes in computed when:

- a key is added to the object
- a value is added/removed from any array

Do I need to use a watch or can this be solely done through computed? A quick an dirty example to see if I get anything back would be:

```
<span v-for="(someArray, someIndex) in getMyObj" v-bind:key="someIndex"> 
 <p> {{someIndex}} - {{JSON.stringify(someArray)}} </p>
</span>

computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['getMyObj'])
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a `watch`, here are two ways to make the property reactive:

**Option one:** Declare the property in your state object:

```
myObj = { someNumericalId: [] };
```

**Option two:** Use `Vue.set` to add the property to your object in mutations:

```
Vue.set(state.myObj, someNumericalId, []);
```

After this, `push` method should automatically trigger updates.

Comment: Option # 2 for the win! Thanks!!

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you *so* much. I was stuck with the most ugly, inelegant hacks to try getting this to work and I felt there had to be a better way — turns out all that's needed indeed is to set up a Vuex nested property with Vue.set. You made *and* saved my day! Thank you!